# File permissions for user that is member of two groups

Tags: linux

Lets' say, user `userX` is a member of group `winners` and group `losers`
There is a file with following permissions:

```
-rw-r-----  userY   winners  1000  May 31 somefile.txt
```

Can `userX` access `somefile.txt`?

Comment: Homwork? :-) Can you show your research effort (as necessary for this site): Do you think he can, and why? If you don't know, did you try it out?

Comment: yes, I tried it on my private computer and I found out that he cannot.

Comment: The experiment still does not answer to the question, since I don't know why is it so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux uses groups as a way to organize users. Groups organize collections of accounts, primarily as a security measure. Control of group membership is administered through the `/etc/group file`, which shows a list of groups and its members.

Every user has a **default or primary group**. When a user logs in, the group membership is set for their primary group. This means that when a user launches a program or creates a file, both the file and the running program will be associated with the user’s current group membership.

A user **may access other files in other groups, as long as they are also a member of that group and the access permissions are set.**

Now if the user wants to creates new files, the permissions will be assigned to the default group, unless specified otherwise. To run programs or create a file in a different group, the user must run the `newgrp <newgroup>` command to switch their current group.

If the user entering the above-referenced command is a member of the `<newgroup>` group in the `/etc/group` file, then the current group membership will change. It is important to note that any files created will now be associated with the `<newgroup>` group rather than the user’s primary group. Users may also change their group by using the `chgrp <group>` command.

**Source:** [Linux Users and Groups](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups)